# Passing Bitmap through activities

Tags: android, kotlin

I have two activities and I am trying to pass image by using Serializable way. How to do this? Is it possible to pass image by using Serializable way? Any ideas please.

```
val resultImage = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.resultImage)
        val getContent = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { uri: Uri? ->
       
            resultImage.setImageURI(uri)
        }


        val galleryBtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.galleryBtn)
        val nextBtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.nextBtn)
     
        
        galleryBtn.setOnClickListener {

            getContent.launch("image/*")

            }

        nextBtn.setOnClickListener {
            val takeImage = resultImage.setImageURI(Uri)

            val person = Person ()

            Intent(this,SecoendActivity::class.java).also {
                it.putExtra("EXTRA_PERSON",person)
                startActivity(it)
            }

        }
```

In kotlin class file:

```
data class Person(

    val imageUrl: Bitmap

    ): Serializable
```

My second activity:

```
val imageView = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView)

val person = intent.getSerializableExtra("EXTRA_PERSON")as Person
```

Comment: You should pass the uri instead. Pass uri.toString().

Comment: "Passing Bitmap through activities" -- unless the bitmaps are very tiny, this is not a good plan. Perhaps you should have only one activity, using fragments or composables for individual screens.

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to use Serializable to pass images between activities, as it can cause memory and performance issues. Instead, you can use the Intent.putExtra method to pass the image's URI to the other activity, and then use the ContentResolver to retrieve the image in the second activity.

```
// In the first activity
val imageUri = Uri.parse("content://...")
val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra("image_uri", imageUri)
startActivity(intent)

// In the second activity
val imageUri = intent.getParcelableExtra<Uri>("image_uri")
val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, imageUri)
```